# How can we dump the output of ncurses based programs to a file in Linux?

Tags: linux, console, ncurses

I tried using tee command, it does not work. I need to get the output of some ncurses bases program (iftop) dumped to a file. Do you know how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try ttyrec or termrec. These programs actually make a recording of the output over time. If you need just a static picture, I think xterm can save a dump of what is currently on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

There is a "man script" utility installed out of the box with most linux distros. It can produce replayable typescripts when option --timing given.